# Ajax requests and racing conditions (client and server side)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, race-condition

Let's imagine the situation that we've sent two similar (almost similar) async ajax requests to server one by one. Because of lag in network, the second request was executed before first request.

```
Ajax request #1: /change/?object_id=1&position=5
Ajax request #2: /change/?object_id=1&position=6
```

In result, we have `object_id=1` position set to `position=5`, but we want `position=6` because `Ajax request #2` was executed after `Ajax request #1` by us.

What is the best practice to avoid this on server side and client side?

Answer (score 1):

Are you worried about racing conditions from the same client or from multiple clients?

If from the same client, I would think the safest bet would be to include a unix timestamp in the ajax request and log this value on the server.  If a request comes with a timestamp that is older than the last logged value, ignore the request (or send a warning back to the browser).

I'm not sure how you would handle multiple clients with unsynchronized clocks...

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I usually put a check in my success handler to make sure that the value being returned is still the one that I want. This will require sending up the parameter you're searching across in the results object.

For example:

```
var query = $('input').val();

$.get('/search', { query: query }, function(res) {
  if(res.query == $('input').val()) {
    //show search results
  }
});
```

I don't know the particulars of your use case, but this general pattern should help.

Answer (score 0):

On the server :

- Build a request table to map request id to timestamp
- Log any request to the server, expect all requests come with timestamp
- If any request comes out of order (e.g. position 6 comes before 5)

  - Check the request table, if it is an earlier request (timestamp) then do not process the request and send an ignore flag
- If it comes in order

  - This is fine, proceed as usual and no need to send any ignore order

On the client:

- When request comes back in, check the ignore flag. If it is there. Don't do anything to the client
- Otherwise proceed as usual by processing the data

Note that this implementation that I suggested requires you to send back and forth data (such as JSON) and not the presentation code (such as HTML fragment) as you would need to check for the ignore flag on the client side.

This answer is similar to what @Farray suggestion of using timestamp.